# Error while installing deepin on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: deepin-desktop-environment

When I try to install `deepin` on Ubuntu 20.04 I get the following error:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.4-051004-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.5.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin for module i915
W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//ubuntudde-text.so) missing, skipping that theme.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.82) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deepin-anything-dkms
 dde-file-manager
 ubuntudde-dde
 deepin-anything-server
 ubuntudde-desktop
 ubuntudde-dde-extras
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve it?

I tried this :

```
apt-cache policy deepin-anything-dkms dde-file-manager  ubuntudde-dde  deepin-anything-server  ubuntudde-desktop  ubuntudde-dde-extras
```

It gave me :

```
deepin-anything-dkms:
  Installed: 5.0.1-4
  Candidate: 5.0.1-4
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.1-4 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
dde-file-manager:
  Installed: 5.0.0-2
  Candidate: 5.0.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.0-2 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntudde-dde:
  Installed: 1.1
  Candidate: 1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
deepin-anything-server:
  Installed: 5.0.1-4
  Candidate: 5.0.1-4
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.1-4 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntudde-desktop:
  Installed: 1.0-10
  Candidate: 1.0-10
  Version table:
 *** 1.0-10 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntudde-dde-extras:
  Installed: 1.0.1
  Candidate: 1.0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1 500
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 ://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I tried : `sudo apt-get install –f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –f
```

Please someone help me with this issue...

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy deepin-anything-dkms dde-file-manager
 ubuntudde-dde  deepin-anything-server  ubuntudde-desktop  ubuntudde-dde-extras` to the question. Also try `sudo apt-get install -f` and add full error log of this command.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-anything`
after you have the `ubuntudde-dev/stable` repo enabled (as you already have),
enable source repo for it in the "Software Sources" or "Software and Updates" GUI program that comes with ubuntu (or use terminal to uncomment the line deb-src line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntudde-dev-ubuntu-stable-focal.list`

`sudo apt-get build-dep deepin-anything-dkms `
`cd deeping-anything`
`dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`
`sudo dpkg --install ../deepin*.deb`

then try installing deepin again

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed the issue. I found this [website](https://www.pigworld.pw/?p=256) (in chinese, but you can translate using google), which seems to have a solution. This is linked to a problem with the deepin-anything-dkms package.

**In this link it asks you to download the kernel ver 5.8**, but I did not had to do it to fix the problem. Focus on the last instructions:

> After inquiring, it should be deeping-anything (
> https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-anything ) that the kernel
> module has a problem. The new version of the kernel has changed the
> structure, resulting in unsuccessful compilation. Modify its source
> code directly
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/source/vfs_change.c
> ```
>
> **Modify time_t on line 128 to ktime_t**
>
> **Amend lines 336-343 as follows:**
>
> ```
> static struct proc_ops procfs_ops = {
>   .proc_open = open_vfs_changes,
>   .proc_read = read_vfs_changes,
>   .proc_ioctl = ioctl_vfs_changes,
>   .proc_lseek = no_llseek,
>   //.llseek = generic_file_llseek,
>   .proc_release = release_vfs_changes,
> };
> ```
>
> You can successfully install the 5.8 kernel by compiling.
>
> Keep it for yourself, or some people may need it.
> After executing these simple steps I executed the following command:

```
sudo apt install sudo apt install deepin-anything-dkms
```

And the issue seemed to be solved.

Comment: Can you explain what do we need to change if we are not using the old 5.8 kernel?

Comment: This helped solving it, but the problem is, changes the source code under var/.../build are reseted when using apt install again, I added a comment the original post, as I'm not able to post answers in this community yet

Answer (score 1):

```
This worked for me.
My kernel version was 5.13 

I updated it to latest.

Bang .... After reboot everything went fine.
```

I followed this answer to update the kernel -https://askubuntu.com/a/1388117/1556074