# 22.04, wifi keeps disconnecting for a few seconds frequently

Tags: networking, kernel, network-manager, iwlwifi

My wifi connection keeps disconnecting frequently (say once in a couple of minutes) sometimes it gets back and sometimes I need to activate and deactivate aeroplane mode.
I tried to change my network provider to make sure it is this laptop problem and not the internet I use. The same happened with ADSL connection, android hotspot, and TD LTE modem.
Really annoying.
Some info:
output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6628]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

and out put of `grep wlan /var/log/kern.log`:

```
Apr 17 21:26:24 mb-X202E kernel: [   18.970719] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
Apr 17 23:49:29 mb-X202E kernel: [   19.312256] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
Apr 18 00:30:25 mb-X202E kernel: [   18.915112] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
Apr 18 12:26:07 mb-X202E kernel: [   21.278385] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
Apr 18 22:21:55 mb-X202E kernel: [   19.425881] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
Apr 21 19:56:26 mb-X202E kernel: [   18.985724] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Ubuntu 22.04

Gnome 42

Asus X202E

Comment: Did you try these solutions? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: @chili555 thank you very much. looks like disabling the power saving works, at least for the recent couple of minutes. I need to wait a little more and see. By the way, when I have set power mode to balanced in power settings, why there must be a power saving setting like that enabled?

Comment: I haven't any ideas as to the balanced power settings. I recommend that you implement all of the other solutions in my post, as well.

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried most of the answers above, some of them worked but the problem started again after a couple  of hours. Finally I installed a fresh Ubuntu and get rid of the disconnection syndrome but the same thing started to happen the day before yesterday.

At last my searches led to a bug with the 5.15 kernel and I found that there are many people facing the same problem with 5.15 and 5.16 kernels. I just updated to the latest kernel (5.17.7) and it has solved the problem for two days now.

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1388117/791329) to update to the latest kernel

Comment: I can confirm this has also resolved my wifi issues. Upgraded the kernel to 6.1.11-060111-generic from 5.15.*

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

And change wifi.powersave to 2

Comment: I had a similar issue with a HP EliteBook 850 G3 with Intel Corporation Wireless 8260. This trick works and avoids messing around with custom kernels.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same bug (same wifi chipset, but in an old Toshiba) after installing Ubuntu 22.04.

Appears to be a bug in the 5.15 kernel, and solved by installing the 5.17 kernel.

I did the following :

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.5-051705_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.5/amd64/linux-modules-5.17.5-051705-generic_5.17.5-051705.202204271406_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then I rebooted, and wifi works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

i had an old machine with (linux ubuntu lts 22.04) internel wifi hardware named intel corporation centrino wireless-n 1000 condor peak. i had tried all methods, installing differnt kernels, but nothing worked me. after rigorous research i found this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274336.
Steps to follow

1. Go to wifi settings
2. Go to ipv6 tab
3. Disable

My wifi is much much faster, Full speed and No slow browsing
reply and give a thumbs up, if this works for you

Comment: Thank you! This one worked for me with 24 hrs+ uptime and no notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Similar behavior, wifi keeps disconnecting and malfunction

my hardware : laptop Asus N751JK
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter

I was runing Ubuntu 20.10, 21.04 up to Ubuntu 21.10 with Kernel 5.13.0 without any problem.
I migrated to Ubuntu 22.04 which installs Kernel 5.15 then the problems started.
I upgraded and tested unsuccessfully the following Kernels : 5.15.28, 5.15.36, 5.16.14, 5.16.20, 5.17.4, 5.17.5

I disabled the power save as explained without improvement in any of the Kernels tested.
Also the "intel_iommu=off" mentioned at https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.kernel/c/RFpPIp0cncA/m/v9ELDxLICgAJ Bug#994590 didn't help.

I downgraded and currently running without any problem using the Kernel 5.13.19-051319-generic.

There is no problem in my airpoint (router) nor my internet access, I have other different computers and devices working correctly on wifi. In addition the N751JK works correctly when using the Ethernet adapter for the physical cable.

more on this
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215703

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215698

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/74187

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215698

Answer (score 2):

So I tried all of the solutions listed here, however, what worked me was upgrading the Kernel to 5.17.14-051714-generic. It's been working  for about 30 minutes. I will update this thread is the issue persists. Fingers crossed!

My specs: Clean install Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Intel Wireless PCI-e card.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723) mentioned in [@chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently#comment2437782_1403773), I tried disabling Power saving and it worked sofar (at least for the recent 20 minutes which is a record):

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

P.S: By the way, when I have set power mode to balanced in power settings, why there must be a power saving setting like that enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a solution, but helped me.

- Being on `Ubuntu 22.04`/`DELL Precision 5540`/`Wireless-AC 9260`
- after multiple upgrades and downgrades
- trying kernels`5.0.0-23`, `5.13.19-051319`, `5.15.0-47`, `5.19.5-051905`

i became desperate and started writing a re-connecting script, following [How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/16588/592445)

But as soon as i tried the first command to connect from terminal:

```
$ nmcli device wifi connect MY_SSID password "MY_PW"
```

The connection became stable and not interrupting any more!

Answer (score 1):

after installing the 5.17 kernel there may be a problem with updating the program core and the appearance of the message system:

**error: bad shim signature.**

**error: you need to load kernel first.**

**press any key to continue...**

it can be fixed by disabling secure boot from BIOS