# Ubuntu 22.04 downloads keep getting failed

Tags: wireless, kernel, network-manager

New to the forum i recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 upgrading via terminal from 20.04. Everything went well as expected but my wifi (only option for connecting to 2.4 GHz) started showing the issue. The downloads start with good speed and then speed drops to 0 every time. I have tried most of the solutions([22.04, wifi keeps disconnecting for a few seconds frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently) started with).
Also refered the solution by @chill555 [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723) still no success. Trying to install Vs-code and other stuff which keep on dropping. Status of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225 [105b:e044]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Can someone help me with the solution please as not able to download anything on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the answer you want to hear, but I was having this exact same issue after upgrading to 22.04 yesterday. After trying all the same suggestions you've mentioned, I was only able to solve it by downgrading my kernel to version 5.14.0. It's possible that a slightly newer version of the Kernel than 5.14.0 will also work, but this is just the version that I randomly decided to try and it appears to have solved the problem for me.

Instructions for downgrading your kernel on Ubuntu can be found [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/downgrade-ubuntu-kernel/)

Comment: This worked like a charm,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to Ubuntu 22.04... I downgraded the kernel using UMKI as suggested by @RustyMonster and the problem is gone. Running kernel 5.15.0 now (was 5.15.30 before)