# Which repository should I use to build Ubuntu Kernel and How should I build to bisect?

Tags: kernel

The Ubuntu Kernels delivered with 22.04 malfunction with my wifi hardware.
I isolated the problem between the kernels :
ok - Mainline Kernel 5.15.4 which corresponds to the Ubuntu Kernel 5.15.0-12.12
nok - Mainline Kernel 5.15.5 which corresponds to the Ubuntu Kernel 5.15.0-13.13

Using the repository (master) at git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack
I can build successfully the commits pointed by the tags 5.15.4 and 5.15.5 but I can not bisect because the commits in between doesn't have the /debian directory.

Using the repository (master) at git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy
I get errors at build like

```
  LD [M]  drivers/iio/industrialio.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/jammy/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/jammy'
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:53: /jammy/debian/stamps/stamp-build-generic] Error 2
```

and I don't know how to find where and what triggers the errors.

In all cases for building I use

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
```

(following what is explained at
[wiki BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and
[wiki KernelMaintenance](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/KernelMaintenance)
)

This is related to :
[launchpad.net bug 1970965](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970965) and [askubuntu 22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)

Comment: Please see: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215703 "No problems found with the recent 5.17.2. Since this regression was fixed I will mark this bug as resolved." Frankly, I'd install 5.17.2 and be done.

Comment: As I said in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970965 I tested mainline 5.17.4 and 5.17.5 and the problem persist so it was not solved at least for my hardware

Comment: You have done a lot of work on your issue. I have bisected the kernel many many times, but only know how to for the mainline, similar to as described in [post 40 of the bugzilla  report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215918#c40). I use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) compile method.