# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi drops after about 1/2 hour

Tags: wireless

I have to restart my computer about every 30 minutes because the wi-fi drops off.  I am new to Ubuntu and not very skilled with the terminal.  I did try the first solution at this link [22.04, wifi keeps disconnecting for a few seconds frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)
Did not solve the situation and now my computer has to go through several extra steps to turn on.
I also set the power save to "off" (i hope)
No solution yet
I also installed a "patch" for the problem.  No luck

Any ideas?
PS it is not the wifi itself.  My other identical computer is still using windows and wifi is always strong.

Thanks

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 14:cb:19:0f:63:68
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-50-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf04000-fcf04fff memory:fcf00000-fcf03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 64:6c:80:67:2b:ff
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.15.0-50-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.254.68 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:46 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fce0ffff
```

Comment: Please consider my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This won't help your WiFi, but for your ethernet interface you should install the `r8168-dkms` driver.  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`  I suggest that because the `r8169` driver on a RTL8168 is asking for trouble and is very unpredictable.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I used the sudo journal...  command above.  Just got hundreds of lines of identical text.  I don't know what "Read man journalctl" means for me to do.