# 22.04 unstable wifi Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01) kernel 5.19

Tags: kernel, iwlwifi, bug-reporting

My wifi connection keeps disconnecting frequently. It's pretty exhausting during meetings.
I've searched how to resolve this bug and I found that it can be related to the kernel version ([22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)).
The actual kernel version is 5.19.0 :

```
(base) claire@claire:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-32-generic
```

I keep trying to downgrade the kernel (5.17.5 ?) with Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer following this tutorial [How to downgrade the Ubuntu kernel](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/downgrade-ubuntu-kernel/).

However I have a problem during the step 3 :

*Step 3: When you’ve finished installing the kernel, reboot. Then, on the Grub boot screen, choose “Advanced Options for Ubuntu” and load the downgraded kernel.*

While I chose the kernel with Grub, I've got the error : `error you need to load the kernel first`.

Is it the right thing to do ?

Here the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` :

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will show your wireless device. Installing an unsupported mainline kernel is not a good choice if even don't know what the problem is. The post you refer to is suggesting to install a newer kernel than it was used at that time in Ubuntu. And the question was about a specific wireless device. It is not a solution for each and every Wi-Fi in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pilot6 , I edit my question with the output :)

Comment: It should work OK. Disconnections way be related to something else, like too many neighbors, etc.

Comment: But my colleague, using the same version of ubuntu, next to me in the office, doesn't have this problem at all

Comment: It could be a hardware problem too.

Comment: I had the problem with my previous computer, which was dying. I have a new one now. And I have still the problem.

Comment: It is unfortunate. The device is a bit too new now.

Comment: What do you mean ? That I can't use ubuntu 22.04 with my laptop ?

Comment: I mean that it is a new device, kernel support may be not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Some have reported success in editing `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and adding the following line.

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1`

You'll need to unload/reload the driver - or more simply restart the system - for the change to take effect.

Comment: I've done this. I'll let you know if the connection is less unstable :)

Comment: I did that but my wifi keep disconnecting often..

Comment: This works on Fedora. The file does not exist, but that's ok.