# 22.04 unstable wifi

Tags: 22.04, iwlwifi

My computer is an ASUS Zenbook 14 OLED BX3402ZA-KM628X. I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it. Since then, my wifi connection keeps disconnecting frequently. I just did a meeting of 30 minutes, I have been disconnected 6 times.

I don't know what to do. Do you have any idea ?

Here the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 :

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Here the kernel installed and used :

```
(base) claire@claire:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-32-generic
```

Thanks !

Comment: My last question was : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455849/22-04-unstable-wifi-intel-corporation-alder-lake-p-pch-cnvi-wifi-808651f0-re 
But I cannot delete it, sorry...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [22.04 unstable wifi Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi \[8086:51f0\] (rev 01) kernel 5.19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455849/22-04-unstable-wifi-intel-corporation-alder-lake-p-pch-cnvi-wifi-808651f0-re)

Comment: No sorry, it's my old question I wanted to delete ...

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: Why  do you want to delete your other question? It has a useful answer and Stack Exchange Network doesn't like to delete good content. Maybe you can copy the content back and forth so that we can save both your updated content from this question and popey's answer.