# Alder lake 1240p processor slow Wifi speeds- ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, madwifi

I was getting good Wifi speeds before 1 month, but recently I noticed my wifi **speed doesn't go above 54mbps** in ubuntu 22.04, **whereas it works perfectly in Windows 11** , I use TP link Wifi 6 router AX70 and as well as TP link wifi AC 1200.

**My wifi hardware:**
**iwconfig output** (few info masked)

```
      wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXXX3"  
         
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
      **Bit Rate=54 Mb/s**   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:358   Missed beacon:0
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 output:**

0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi    [8086:51f0] (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I tried the solution provided here [22.04 unstable wifi Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01) kernel 5.19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455849/22-04-unstable-wifi-intel-corporation-alder-lake-p-pch-cnvi-wifi-808651f0-re)  , But didn't work. I have the exact same wifi hardware, and tried with **kernel 5.15.0-60,5.19.0-38 & even 6.1.0-1008**, but no luck!.

Below solution doesn't work
for disable n network  in **/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf**

**options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1**

Please let me know how I can I resolve this, or any other driver that I can install?.

Answer (score 0):

The driver parameter that you added has exactly the effect you are seeing: slow speeds. I suggest that you remove this line entirely from iwlwifi.conf:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1
```

Next, unload and reload the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

There are also some steps you can take with your router to help stability. First, use fixed channels, like 11 and 149, rather than auto-channel select. Second, Use WPA2/WPA3 only, not any mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Third, rename the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments of your router; something like *myrouter2.4* and *myrouter5*. Direct your computer to use the 5 gHz segment only.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but I don't understand, I enabled this becoz of wifi slowness, but now I disable it and now its working!!, strange.

Comment: You got bad advice. That might help stability but not slowness.