# Kubutu 22.04 does not boot with kernel 5.19.0-41 or 5.19.0-42

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, lts

I hope I provided enought context, I run Kubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 15 9520, after recent Kernel Updates, since Kernel version 5.19.0-41-generic, my machine won't come up, also with 5.19.0-42-generic, same issue it stucks after that (or similar) output: (dmesg file)

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Linux version 5.19.0-41-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-045) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17)
[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic 
...
[   32.671018] kernel: Call Trace:
[   32.671994] kernel:  <TASK>
[   32.672977] kernel:  ? nv_drm_master_set+0x22/0x50 [nvidia_drm]
[   32.673987] kernel:  drm_new_set_master+0xa6/0x130 [drm]
[   32.674954] kernel:  drm_master_open+0x93/0xc0 [drm]
[   32.675925] kernel:  drm_open+0xf8/0x270 [drm]
[   32.676861] kernel:  drm_stub_open+0xb7/0x140 [drm]
[   32.677842] kernel:  chrdev_open+0xc4/0x250
[   32.678764] kernel:  ? __unregister_chrdev+0x60/0x60
[   32.680208] kernel:  do_dentry_open+0x167/0x400
[   32.681150] kernel:  vfs_open+0x2d/0x40
[   32.682152] kernel:  do_open+0x223/0x490
[   32.683050] kernel:  path_openat+0x11d/0x2c0
[   32.683962] kernel:  ? check_heap_object+0x16b/0x1e0
[   32.684885] kernel:  do_filp_open+0xb2/0x160
[   32.685841] kernel:  ? __check_object_size+0x23/0x30
[   32.686743] kernel:  ? alloc_fd+0xb9/0x180
[   32.687644] kernel:  do_sys_openat2+0xb3/0x180
[   32.688561] kernel:  __x64_sys_openat+0x55/0xa0
[   32.689489] kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[   32.690410] kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[   32.691320] kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[   32.692243] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[   32.693156] kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[   32.694097] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[   32.695004] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[   32.695996] kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[   32.696993] kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[   32.698005] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[   32.698925] kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
[   32.699833] kernel:  ? sysvec_call_function+0x4e/0xb0
[   32.700754] kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[   32.701691] kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f0fba3146eb
[   32.702612] kernel: Code: 25 00 00 41 00 3d 00 00 41 00 74 4b 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 67 44 89 e2 48 89 ee bf 9c ff ff ff b8 01 01 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 0f 87 91 00 00 00 48 8b 54 24 28 64 48 2b 14 25
[   32.703546] kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe20c4a910 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
[   32.705023] kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 00007f0fba3146eb
[   32.706036] kernel: RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 00007ffe20c4a9e0 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
[   32.706987] kernel: RBP: 00007ffe20c4a9e0 R08: 00007f0fba3d1460 R09: 00007ffe20c4a820
[   32.707937] kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
[   32.708894] kernel: R13: 00005629260e4e1d R14: 00005629260ecaf8 R15: 00007f0fba607040
[   32.709948] kernel:  </TASK>
[   32.711017] kernel: Modules linked in: intel_tcc_cooling cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_ctl_led snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_hda_codec_realtek soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine overlay snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp iwlmvm(+) snd_hda_codec bnep snd_hda_core dell_laptop snd_hwdep coretemp mac80211 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel nvidia_drm(O) binfmt_misc snd_rawmidi kvm nvidia_modeset(O) btusb mei_hdcp mei_pxp intel_rapl_msr libarc4 uvcvideo btrtl snd_seq processor_thermal_device_pci hid_sensor_als processor_thermal_device btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc hid_sensor_trigger btintel videobuf2_memops dell_wmi btmtk
[   32.711047] kernel:  industrialio_triggered_buffer iwlwifi snd_seq_device videobuf2_v4l2 rapl processor_thermal_rfim ledtrig_audio nls_iso8859_1 bluetooth input_leds snd_timer intel_cstate videobuf2_common nvidia(O) dell_wmi_sysman(+) processor_thermal_mbox cmdlinepart dell_smbios ucsi_acpi kfifo_buf mei_me videodev spi_nor dcdbas ecdh_generic serio_raw typec_ucsi snd hid_sensor_iio_common firmware_attributes_class processor_thermal_rapl dell_wmi_descriptor mc ecc cfg80211 mtd wmi_bmof mei hid_multitouch(+) soundcore industrialio intel_rapl_common igen6_edac typec int3403_thermal dptf_power int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid intel_hid int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt nvme nvme_core ahci libahci hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_hid i915 drm_buddy i2c_algo_bit ttm hid_generic drm_display_helper rtsx_pci_sdmmc cec rc_core
[   32.714429] kernel:  crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel drm_kms_helper syscopyarea aesni_intel sysfillrect sysimgblt crypto_simd fb_sys_fops cryptd psmouse i2c_i801 spi_intel_pci drm rtsx_pci spi_intel intel_lpss_pci i2c_smbus thunderbolt intel_ish_ipc intel_lpss intel_ishtp xhci_pci idma64 vmd xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[   32.719392] kernel: CR2: 0000000000000040
[   32.720733] kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[   33.207264] kernel: RIP: 0010:GrabOwnership+0x8/0x40 [nvidia_modeset]
[   33.208782] kernel: Code: bf 06 00 00 00 e8 f8 bd 05 00 b8 01 00 00 00 5d c3 90 31 c0 c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 83 ec 18 <8b> 57 40 b8 01 00 00 00 48 c7 44 24 08 00 00 00 00 85 d2 74 1c 48
[   33.210306] kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffbb9e4a56ba68 EFLAGS: 00010292
[   33.211602] kernel: RAX: ffffffffc1bc8c20 RBX: ffff909dd4a38800 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   33.212892] kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff909dcd2aea00 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   33.214214] kernel: RBP: ffffbb9e4a56ba90 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   33.216136] kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff909dd4a38800
[   33.217490] kernel: R13: ffff909dcf31b8c0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff909dcd2aea10
[   33.218827] kernel: FS:  00007f0fba43b740(0000) GS:ffff90ad0f380000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   33.220291] kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   33.221778] kernel: CR2: 0000000000000040 CR3: 0000000111b10003 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
[   33.223201] kernel: PKRU: 55555554
[   33.285746] kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 505.
[   33.469823] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
[   33.473707] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
[   33.478461] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
[   33.482218] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
[   33.486077] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
[   33.491177] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=13 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
[   33.499873] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=14 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input33
[   33.501066] kernel: input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:311C Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:311C.0002/input/input37
[   33.504189] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=15 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input34
[   33.505548] kernel: input: VEN_04F3:00 04F3:311C Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-VEN_04F3:00/0018:04F3:311C.0002/input/input38
[   33.508590] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=16 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input35
[   33.510082] kernel: hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:311C.0002: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [VEN_04F3:00 04F3:311C] on i2c-VEN_04F3:00
[   33.513726] kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=17 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input36
[   33.950909] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   33.965327] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[   33.977218] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[   33.979458] kernel: thermal thermal_zone13: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[   34.107424] kernel: loop22: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[   34.108292] kernel: I/O error, dev loop22, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   34.147096] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded PNVM version 881c99e1
[   34.163556] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
[   34.235649] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 14:75:5b:d5:e3:dc
[   34.256676] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[   34.309510] kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   34.314283] kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
[   34.655706] kernel: Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   34.814183] kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[   34.817410] kernel: 
[   34.820001] kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_OSC]
[   34.821571] kernel: 
[   34.822933] kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_OSC]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   34.824147] kernel:   Arg0:   000000002169fa14 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 5D A8 3B B2 B7 C8 42 35
[   34.825412] kernel:   Arg1:   00000000149913af <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[   34.826659] kernel:   Arg2:   000000008e5ad9e4 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   34.828019] kernel:   Arg3:   000000009498dfff <Obj>           Buffer(8) 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00
[   34.829329] kernel: 
[   34.831127] kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
```

after 2h google I gave up to identify the issue on my own.

Comment: my workaround right now is to go to grub menu, advanced options and start system with 5.19.0-40-generic kernel (this works)

Comment: What BIOS are you running? Is it the latest for your machine? For an update, use https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-de/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=tjkgw for the newest version 1.3.0 as of today.

Comment: @emk2203 the latest one is: 1.13.1 from 2023-05-03 (https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-de/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=x9px4&oscode=biosa&productcode=xps-15-9520-laptop) in use on my machine

Comment: This looks clearly like a kernel issue. Maybe you can try a newer kernel from a more recent release. I am running Mantic here with kernel 6.2.0-21. The system should be fine with this kernel. You'll need linux-headers, linux-image, linux-modules and linux-modules-extra, followed by <kernel version> and generic most likely.

Comment: can I somewhere see changes done in kernel version between 5.19.0-40 and 5.19.0-41? some of these changes broke it.

Comment: The reason to try a more recent kernel is to determine if the issue has already been fixed upstream, and if it has the fix will likely trickle down to the 5.19 series eventually. I suggest the most recent mainline kernel (currently [6.4-rc3](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.4-rc3/)), as a test. To determine the exact commit that caused the issue you would need to bisect the kernel, which typically involves compiling and testing the kernel around 20 times.

Comment: OK I try out, but i need some Instruction on how to Update the Kernel Version. Can someone provide me a web Tutorial on how to do that (I just googled and found 3 different approaches), do I need to add any repository? (does this fits for my case? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one)

Comment: The method used in your link should be fine.

Comment: Ok, good thing is: kernel 6.3.3-060303-generic seems to work. Comparing the Logs I have to say that the stacktrace starting at [32.671018] seems to be the issue (you guys probably already know that). nether in 5.19.0-40, nor in 6.3.3-060303 this (or any) stacktrace appears, so you were right, problem already fixed in later versions. Now i am running 22.04 LTS with a far newer kernel than is targeted for this release. Do I have anything to consider eg. when doing Updates? or anything I should know? And should I close this Question with Answer directing to the comments?