Can't detect my laptops inbuilt microphone
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-26 16:55:32

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 6
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 5 7535HS with Radeon™ Graphics × 12
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Disk Capacity:                               512.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            R2KET27W (1.10 )
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-49-generic

Changed from windows to Ubuntu. The built in microphone is not recognized. Output sound works fine. Plugged in microphones also works fine.
alsamixer
sound settings

Try updating your computer: Press Alt and F2 (may require the Fn key to be pressed) key, then type gnome-terminal and press Enter. A purple window will pop up. Into it, type:
sudo apt update && yes | sudo apt upgrade && yes | sudo apt --purge autoremove

Then press Enter. Type in your password, not the root user's password. (If you did not set up a sudo user, do su -c "usermod -aG sudo username", type in the root user's password, and try the sudo command again.) Your computer may install a driver automatically.
Look at Jag Jenki's answer too.
Try to find drivers online (from Lenovo) and install them. (I'm having difficulty finding them but they seem to exist after some research.) They don't exist.
Edit: Looks like someone had the same problem and fixed it by updating the kernel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/785062. You may not have to update the kernel manually, maybe using the script mentioned here - https://cloudspinx.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu/ - or if it goes down - https://askubuntu.com/a/1388117/2021441. Or you can wait for the next (LTS?) release (which I'm not even sure will upgrade the kernel). Also, looking at the Ubuntu certified page Jag Jenki shared, your computer seems to support 22.04, not 24.04. Also, the hardware details mention nothing about a microphone. Consider using an external microphone for now.

I can't find any drivers from Lenovo at all except for some pc model

check out the edit

It seems like they only have drivers for Windows?

Updating the kernel worked. Thank you!

You're welcome!

Hey @Confucius, if this helped, please click the checkmark icon. This both gives me reputation and tells other people that this worked for you.

There are a few solutions you could try but let's start with the simplest:
Your laptop model is Ubuntu Certified and is available in some regions preconfigured with Ubuntu. However, those models are using the OEM kernel which may solve this issue.
So you should try installing the alternative kernel and seeing if that solves the issue.
Open a terminal and input this command. Note that this will downgrade you to an older version of Ubuntu at first but once this kernel is installed, Ubuntu should automatically keep you on the OEM branch of the kernel so if it offers to update you back up to 24.04, it should be safe to do so.
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04d 

Here is the Ubuntu Certifed page for your laptop https://ubuntu.com/certified/202403-33875

I tried the command but I got
E: Unable to locate package linux-oem-22.04d
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-oem-22.04d'

I believe the OEM branch was removed in favor of plain virtual kernels.  I also don't believe there is a linux-oem branch in Ubuntu 24.04 and later either, hence why they can't install it.  Note that 22.04 was what they were certified for, not 24.04, so there may not be an OEM certification/branch of the kernel for 24.04

So I have to use ubuntu 22.04 for my microphone to work?
